# I am trying to covert this normal code to foreach:

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, meta

I created wordpress gallery using custom metabox and my code is giving right output as i want.
But trying to make it in standard way.

**Original Code**

```
$mytheme_gallery_one = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mytheme_image_one', true ); 
$mytheme_image_one_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $mytheme_gallery_one, 'large' ); 
$mytheme_image_one_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $mytheme_gallery_one );

$mytheme_gallery_two = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mytheme_image_two', true ); 
$mytheme_image_two_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $mytheme_gallery_two, 'large' ); 
$mytheme_image_two_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $mytheme_gallery_two );

$mytheme_gallery_three = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mytheme_image_three', true ); 
$mytheme_image_three_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $mytheme_gallery_three, 'large' ); 
$mytheme_image_three_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $mytheme_gallery_three );
?>
<figure class="fit-vid ed-youtube">
    <a href="<?php echo $mytheme_image_one_url; ?>" ><?php echo $mytheme_image_one_image; ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $mytheme_image_two_url; ?>" ><?php echo $mytheme_image_two_image; ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $mytheme_image_two_url; ?>" ><?php echo $mytheme_image_two_image; ?></a>
</fiture>
```

I am trying to make it short using **foreach**:

```
foreach {
   my_theme_gallery;
   my_theme_image;
   my_theme_url
<figure class="fit-vid ed-youtube">
    <a href="<?php echo $mytheme_image_one_url; ?>" ><?php echo $mytheme_image_one_image; ?></a>
</fiture>
}
```

and need output of multiple images as uploaded.

Comment: @MarcB He posted his original code, he posted his attempt (In the foreach loop). While not a great question, I think that's a bit rude.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest way:

```
<figure class="fit-vid ed-youtube">
<?php

foreach ( array('one', 'two', 'three') as $theme )
{
    $mytheme_gallery = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mytheme_image_' . $theme, true );
    $mytheme_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $mytheme_gallery, 'large' );
    $mytheme_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $mytheme_gallery );

    echo '<a href="', $mytheme_image_url, '" >', $mytheme_image, '</a>';

}

?>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, should be work, but is that possible to manage array in different way.  if we have array like this in sequence.
mytheme_image_1', 
'mytheme_image_2',
'mytheme_image_3

Comment: What? Clarify exactly what you want in your original question

Comment: Your solution is working fine, but can we make array's short? indeed of _one, _tow, _three etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it works for you, please be sure to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure class="fit-vid ed-youtube">
<?php

**foreach ( array('one', 'two', 'three') as $theme )**
{
    $mytheme_gallery = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mytheme_image_' . $theme, true );
    $mytheme_image = wp_get_attachment_image( $mytheme_gallery, 'large' );
    $mytheme_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $mytheme_gallery );

    echo '<a href="', $mytheme_image_url, '" >', $mytheme_image, '</a>';

}

?>
</figure>
```

instead of using multiple arryas, if we have more then 20+ arrays. is that possible to make something like this?
**foreach ( array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' and more) as $theme )**
**foreach ( array('one+1') as $theme )**
or something live this?